# Convert JSON Array to Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I'm having a difficult time trying to convert the following JSON response:

```
string json = "{\"results\":{\"Letters\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]}}";
```

To a dictionary that looks like this:

- Key: "a", Value: "Source A"
- Key: "b", Value: "Source A"
- Key: "C", Value: "Source A"

My plan is to pull two json objects with the same format, from different data sources, merge them into one dictionary and use the Value to determine where they came from.

Thanks

Comment: Where does `Source A` value come from?

Comment: It's just hard-coded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your JSON into [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), then convert `Letters` array into `Dictionary<string, string>` using [`ToDictionary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8) method (with every value hardcoded to `Source A`)

```cs
string data = "{\"results\":{\"Letters\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]}}";
var json = JObject.Parse(data);
var letters = json["results"]?["Letters"] as JArray;
var dict = letters.ToDictionary(l => l.Value<string>(), _ => "Source A");
```

Comment: I would like the result to be this
[a]: "Source A"
[b]: "Source A"
[c]: "Source A"

Rather than this:
    [0]: {[a, Source A]}
    [1]: {[b, Source A]}
    [2]: {[c, Source A]}

Comment: @rdg515 Have you tried to run the code above? It gives you a `Dictionary<string, string>` as result, where every key is a letter and every value is `Source A` (format mentioned in your question), nor an array or json

Comment: My apologies, you're right, when I wrote the dict object the format threw me.  Thanks very much!